# Why my iframe maps is display overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have a question, I use iframe for display my google map service in my web application. But Why my iframe maps is display overlapping? (it's mean now i have a 2 map in 2 layer)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCOPU.jpg)

i want to find the solution about iframe overlapping for my problem and solve it. Thanks.

This My iframe Code

```
div class="map-responsive">
                        <!-- embed code here -->
                        <iframe id="map_locations" src="#" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>


                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.map-responsive iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```